# Soundpool different streamid

Tags: android, soundpool

I have soundpool that will load file from sd-card and I used mstreamID to stop it and I use mstreamID in OnLoadCompleteListener so the files can load. I use 2 buttons to play soundpool diffrent sounds. But when I click first button and while it plays 1 sound I click second button and it stops the sound from first button.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Settings {
        SoundPool mSoundPool;
        int mSoundId;
        int mStreamId = 0;
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
            mSoundPool
                    .setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool,
                                int sampleId, int status) {
                            mStreamId = soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
}
                });

    }
//OnClick
public void button1(View view) {
        if (mStreamId != 0) {
            mSoundPool.stop(mStreamId);
        }
// et1 is extended from Settings.java
        String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), et1.getText()
                .toString());
        mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(path, 1);
    }
public void button2(View view) {
        if (mStreamId != 0) {
            mSoundPool.stop(mStreamId);
        }

        String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), et2.getText()
                .toString());
        mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(path, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Read doc please, and what is the thing you want to say?

1. do not load same file more than one time if you not unload it.
2. load all sound at start when use SoundPool.
3. streamId is increasing all the time, you never get same streamId.